# IntelliJ 15.0.6 meta key stopped working on MacOSX

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, emacs

I am using IntelliJ on a mac with a windows keyboard. I set it up to use emacs keybindings, where ctrl is C and alt is M. I don't remember changing any settings, but now, I can't use M. If I do, it just uses mac shortcuts (i.e. M-; gives me an ellipsis instead of making a line comment). This problem does not happen in my terminal. Also, if I go to Preferences -> Keymap, and do a Find Actions By Shortcut, the M key works (searching for M-; gives me Comment with line comment). Also, I should point out that all shortcuts that require C work.

MacOS version: El Capitan, 10.11.5